# video streaming using customtkinter

Tags: python, opencv, tkinter, python-imaging-library, customtkinter

How to video streaming using customtkinter library in class method form ?
i was troubling to configure how to that, i see many examples but i dont know how to implement this on my code

```
# code for video streaming
def camera(self):
    ret, img = cap.read()
    cv2image= cv2.cvtColor(cap.read()[1],cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    img = Image.fromarray(cv2image)
    ImgTks = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image=img)
    self.camera.imgtk = ImgTks
    self.camera.configure(image=ImgTks)
    self.after(20,self.camera)
    

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = TimeIn()
    app.camera()
    app.mainloop()
```

this is my whole code for this
https://github.com/Fsociety-Mrn/videostreamingCutsomkinter

please do help me i am new to this

Comment: You should not use same name `camera` on a label and function.

Comment: Is my answer working for you?

Comment: Better post the code in the question instead of a link.

Answer (score 2):

The main issue is that you have used same name `camera` for a label and a function.  Just rename the function to other name, for example `streaming()`:

```py
...
class TimeIn(customtkinter.CTk):
    ...
    # code for video streaming
    def streaming(self):
        ret, img = cap.read()
        cv2image= cv2.cvtColor(cap.read()[1], cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        img = Image.fromarray(cv2image)
        ImgTks = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image=img)
        self.camera.imgtk = ImgTks
        self.camera.configure(image=ImgTks)
        self.after(20, self.streaming)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = TimeIn()
    app.streaming()
    app.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

Using tkinter_webcam module:-

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter_webcam import webcam
 
window = tk.Tk()  # Sets up GUI
window.title("Example")  # Titles GUI
window.geometry("1000x1000")  # Sizes GUI
 
# Uses Box class from webcam to create video window
video = webcam.Box(window, width=450, height=450)
video.show_frames()  # Show the created Box
 
tk.mainloop()
```